# Join subquery with a count function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four tables:

1. `Room` (holds room details)
2. `property`( holds property details)
3. `property interest` (linking table matching customers with properties 
        interested in)
4. `buying_potential_customer` (customer details).

I currently have this query which tells me how many rooms in each property has.

```
SELECT
  property.property_id,
  property.property_address_first_line,
  COUNT(room.property_id) AS number_of_rooms
FROM room
INNER JOIN property
  ON room.property_id = property.property_id
GROUP BY property.property_id,
         property.property_address_first_line
ORDER BY property.property_id;
```

The property_interest and buying_potential interest need to be joined to this also.

This is the property interest table

[image: property interest table]

This is the buying potential customer table

[image: buying potential customer]

In the end I need, the data from property interest which matches property with buyer but with the buyer's first and last name attached, additionally counting the number of rooms in the property which is the query above. It seems I would need a subquery but am not sure how to complete this, and help would be appreciated

Sorry I am quite new to SQL.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Oracle, sorry I apologise :)

Comment: Please show the results you want from the example data you have given.

Comment: It's basic `join` / `group by query`, no complications, just add two more joins like you did already for `rooms` table, here is [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/394).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your aim :)

You must write a query as main table your middle table `property_interest`, so you can join it with others parent tables, as follow:

```
SELECT bpc.buying_customer_first_name || bpc.buying_customer_surname,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM room r
JOIN property p
    ON r.property_id = p.property_id
WHERE p.property_id = pi.property_id)
FROM property_interest pi
JOIN buying_potential_custoter bpc
    ON pi.buying_customer_id = bpc.buying_customer_id
```